# Do-while loop exception

Tags: java, exception, do-while

This code is designed to get ten user-input integers, and find the max value as well as the index of that max value. I'm required to use a do while loop for this specific version.

I can enter the ten numbers, however, there is an exception when trying to get the largest number and its index. I'm not entirely sure how to go about fixing this. Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!

```
final int[] numbers;
numbers = new int[10];
int largest = numbers[0];
int largest_i = 0;
int counter = 0;

final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers: ");


do {
    numbers[counter] = keyboard.nextInt();
    counter++;
} while (counter < numbers.length);

if (numbers[counter] >= largest) {
    largest = numbers[counter];
    largest_i = counter;
}
System.out.print("The largest number is: " + largest);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("That number is stored at index " +  largest_i);
```

Comment: Can you post the exception and the stack trace?

Comment: please post the exception stack trace

Comment: Put the `if` block inside the `do-while` loop. As it is, you're 1) only checking a single number if it's the largest, and 2) using `counter` when its value is necessarily greater than the largest index of `numbers`

Comment: After your `while` loop the `counter` variable is exactly equal to the size of the array, meaning you are trying to access one value past its bounds

Comment: your logic of finding max number isnt right, apart from indexoutofbound exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting an index out of bounds exception. This is because you do the if check outside the loop.

```
if (numbers[counter] >= largest)...
```

However, at this point, counter is 10, while the indexes only go from 0-9.

Move the if block into the loop to check for the max value.

```
do {
    numbers[counter] = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (numbers[counter] >= largest) {
       largest = numbers[counter];
       largest_i = counter;
    }
    counter++;
} while (counter < numbers.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you find the largest number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[10];
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//set largest to minimum value

        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;

        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers: ");


        do {
            numbers[counter] = keyboard.nextInt();//get the numbers here
            keyboard.nextLine();
            if(numbers[counter]>largest){//compare the entered number with the current largest number, if greater assign largest to the current number
                largest = numbers[counter];
                index = counter;//store the index of the largest number found 
            }
            counter++;//increment array counter
        } while (counter < numbers.length);

        System.out.print("The largest number is: " + largest);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("That number is stored at index " +  index);

    }
```